# How to return end digits of a long in C (specifically when they are 0's)

Tags: c, math

I've been working through a credit card problem and I've had trouble figuring out how to extract ending digits of a number, for example doing 123 % 10 to get 3, 123 % 100 to get 23 etc etc. But the problem I'm having is with a number such as 6310005 where % 10 through to 10000 all return simply 5 whereas I would like it to return 5,05,005 etc. [Here is a link to the output of findDoubles(378282246310005,15,1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBZxu.png)

```
long* findDoubles(long cardNum, int cardLength, int startIndex)
{
    long length = 0;
    // if starting at the second number, and counting there on
    if(startIndex == 1 )
    {
        length = floor(cardLength/2);
    }
    else
    {
        length = ceil(cardLength/2);
    }
    long *doublesArr = malloc(length);
    for (int i = startIndex; i < length; i++)
    {
        doublesArr[i] = cardNum % (long)pow(10,i);
        printf("\ndoublesArr[%i] = %lu",i, doublesArr[i]);
    }
    return doublesArr;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Is your goal to change your print line to show the leading zeros? This won't change the actual output array just FYI, because 5 == 05 == 005 etc.

Comment: it is not a good idea to use a float function `pow` in a purely integer calculation.

Comment: Yes, that is the goal, I'm trying to work through a lunhs algorithm problem

Comment: Are you aware that 5 and 05 are the same number? "I want to know the last letter of a sentence someone said, but my problem is I don't know whether it's a capital letter"

Comment: Please don't store credit card numbers as integer types.

Comment: The cardNumbers are stored as longs, and yes I'm aware they are the same number, I'm just trying to get the leading 0's, I should probably reword the question a bit. For reference, here is the entire code so far https://pastebin.com/i4cbf5cf

Comment: Processing the numbers as strings instead of long values would be trivial. Look into `sprintf` to convert the long to a sting and then you can simply index the digits you are interested in. Using `modulo` will never preserve leading zeros.

Comment: The difference between 5, 05, and 005 in your example all come down to how you print the value `5`.    They are all the same value, so you need to output them differently.    If `CardNum % 1000` gives a value of `5`, then you need to produce leading zeros on output using a different format string - not try to change the value of `5` to `005`.

Comment: Also, you're better off encoding credit numbers as a string - for example `"6310005"`.   Then just extract the last three digits as another string, if that's what you seek.

Answer (score 2):

Before I say this, let me stress that you ***should not store credit card numbers as integers.***

However... the key is that, after you get the remainder from your modulus operation, you need to subtract that from your initial value and then divide the initial value by your base.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned long long int CC = 1234123412341234; 
  unsigned long long int temp = CC;
  unsigned short int A[16] = { 0 };
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    A[15-i] = temp % 10;
    temp = temp - A[15-i];
    temp = temp / 10;
  }

  printf("As an unsigned long long int, the CC number is %llu\n", CC);
  printf("As individual digits in an array, the CC number is ");

  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    printf("%1d", A[i]);
  }

  printf("\n\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that loop is much cleaner than what I had planned in my head, I'll fiddle around with it and implement it, thank you

Comment: Okay, but you got the part about not storing these as integer types right?  Why aren't you using a string for a credit card number?

Comment: Yes, I understand that part :). My original idea was to use a string as it would make this a extreme amount easier, but I wanted to learn the math approach to it.

Answer (score 1):

Handling the partial card number beginning at `startindex` is quite a bit easier when done as a sting. Given that a `long` can require no more than `21-chars` (including the sign and *nul-terminating* character), a simple buffer with automatic storage duration is all that is required. You can pass the buffer as a parameter and simply return the `startindex` within the string (created by a simple call to `sprintf`) as a character pointer from `finddoubles`.

A simple example would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXSTR 32   /* max chars for long is 21 */

char *finddoubles (long cardnum, int cardlength, int startindex, char *str)
{
    if (!str) {     /* check valid address for str */
        fputs ("error: str unallocated pointer.\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* validate conversion matches cardlength */
    if (sprintf (str, "%ld", cardnum) != cardlength) {
        fputs ("error: conversion not cardlength chars.\n", stderr);
        return NULL;
    }

    return &str[startindex];    /* return requesting substring at index */
}

int main (void) {

    long num = 6310005;   /* example credit card number */
    int len = 7;          /* length */
    char str[MAXSTR];     /* buffer for conversion - avoids allocation */

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)   /* output values for all startindexes */
        printf ("start index: %d  indexed card no.: %s\n",
                i, finddoubles (num, len, i, str));
}
```

(**note:** you can simply assign the return to a character pointer (e.g. `char *p = finddoubles (num, len, i, str);` for use rather than immediately printing the value)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cardnumidx
start index: 0  indexed card no.: 6310005
start index: 1  indexed card no.: 310005
start index: 2  indexed card no.: 10005
start index: 3  indexed card no.: 0005
start index: 4  indexed card no.: 005
start index: 5  indexed card no.: 05
start index: 6  indexed card no.: 5
```

There are a myriad of ways to do this. The simplest is using `sprintf`. There is no need to roll your own conversion as `sprintf` is part of the standard library. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

**Edit for 16-char Cardnum**

If as explained in the comments, credit card numbers are always 16 character, then simple *padding* and *field width* modifiers for `sprintf` will insure you index the entire card number with the following modifications, e.g.

```
    ...
    if (sprintf (str, "%016ld", cardnum) != cardlength) {
    ...
    int len = 16;
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf ("start index: %2d  indexed card no.: %s\n",
        ...
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cardnumidx
start index:  0  indexed card no.: 0000000006310005
start index:  1  indexed card no.: 000000006310005
start index:  2  indexed card no.: 00000006310005
start index:  3  indexed card no.: 0000006310005
start index:  4  indexed card no.: 000006310005
start index:  5  indexed card no.: 00006310005
start index:  6  indexed card no.: 0006310005
start index:  7  indexed card no.: 006310005
start index:  8  indexed card no.: 06310005
start index:  9  indexed card no.: 6310005
start index: 10  indexed card no.: 310005
start index: 11  indexed card no.: 10005
start index: 12  indexed card no.: 0005
start index: 13  indexed card no.: 005
start index: 14  indexed card no.: 05
start index: 15  indexed card no.: 5
```

**NOTE `long` cannot hold 16-digits on all systems**

As astutely pointed out by [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4593267/chqrlie) in the comments below, on legacy systems, e.g. X86, a `long` value is only 32-bits and only capable of a rage from `-2147483648 to 2147483647` and incapable of holding 16-digits. To remedy, best to use *exact size type* defined in `stdint.h` such as `int64_t` (for your `long`) or better `uint64_t` as using a signed number makes little sense here. The corresponding print macros for exact size types are provided in `inttypes.h`.

Comment: For starters, credit card numbers take exactly 16 characters.

Comment: That helps, I was just going by his example and making sure it could cover the full range of the `long` - figured I would cover it either way.

Comment: You might also mention that type `long` might not have the required range to store 16 digit numbers. For portability to legacy systems where `long` has only 31 value bits, such as Microsoft Windows, one should use `long long` or `unsigned long long`, or fast better, a `char` array.

Comment: Yes, you are good. Exact size types would be quite nice here. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

> to return end digits of a `long`

This is simply a "mod" of the `long` by some power-of-10.

To retain leading zeros in printing, use `".*"` or a *precision* as part of `printf()` for direct output, or `sprintf()` to save to a *string*.

Since CC number typically exceed 10 digits, better to use a wider type that certainly can accommodate as `long` may be insufficient.  `unsigned long long` can handle all 19 digit numbers - at least.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long pow10_ull(unsigned y) {
  unsigned long long z = 1;
  unsigned long long base = 10;
  while (y) {
    if (y % 2) {
      z *= base;
    }
    y /= 2;
    base *= base;
  }
  return z;
}

unsigned long long endDigits(unsigned long long cardNum, int endLength) {
  return cardNum % pow10_ull(endLength);
}

void printEndDigits(unsigned long long cardNum, int cardLength,
    int startIndex) {
  int endLength = cardLength - startIndex;
  printf("%.*llu\n", endLength, endDigits(cardNum, endLength));
}

int main() {
  printEndDigits(378282246310005, 15, 1);
  printEndDigits(378282246310005, 15, 11);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
78282246310005
0005
```